horizon scrolling scroll the body but not scrolled the headers
I am using ag-grid with pinned columns .
Horizontal scrolling from time to time the header row does not scroll together with the data rows.
Our solution for such a case is to delete the history of the browser and then browsing works properly
Are you aware of this problem and if so, in which version is this problem fixed?
